# RPM %files absolute path issue

Tags: rpm-spec

I am relatively new to creating RPM packages. I am using Fedora 19 OS , I am not able to make RPM pick %files from absolute path. Please advice on the same

```
Name: SampleRpm
Version: 1
License: none
Release: 5.6
buildroot: /root/rpmbuild
prefix: /root/rpmbuild
Summary: Sample
Group: Applications/Sample
%prep
rm -r /home/siva/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
%build
cd /home/siva/repos/centina/sa
ant clean make-private dist
cp /home/siva/repos/centina/sa/dist/Sample.zip /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES

%install
cp /home/siva/repos/centina/sa/dist/Sample.zip /root/setup
cd /root/setup
unzip Sample.zip
chmod +x setup.sh
./setup.sh -o
%description
empty
%files
/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES
```

i get the following error

```
error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/SampleRpm-1-5.6.x86_64/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`%files` is where the final files will be. I would recommend finding an RPM primer online - there are many that walk you right thru step by step.